# extract string using regex in java

Tags: java

I need help in order to extract 2 strings in JAVA using regex from the following string:

```
"Batch job <jobid> <jobtype> success"
```

I need to take out the jobid and job type.
When i put the string from a get() method to an String object I get the `<` replaced with `&lt`; which is literal.

How can I compose regex expression to extract the jobid and jobtype from my String?
The strings should be without the `<>`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What job id? What job type? I see neither of those things in "Batch job success" ....

Comment: What do you mean by "put the string from a get() method"?

Comment: I mean I extract the String from an object. ex String message = object.getMessage();

Comment: Please edit your question with some example strings and what you expect from them, with the exact characters you are expecting so we don't have to guess

Comment: Ok I updated the entry, I expect to take out the two strings out of the < > .

Comment: @Vlad it is still unclear since you only mention `<` being replaced with `&lt;`, but you say nothing of `>` being changed into `&gt;` (the [html names](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) for those characters. If you could give us a complete line like `Batch job &lt;1234&gt; &lt;normal&lt; success` and tell us you want to extract `1234` and `normal`, we could answer your question. Help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, giving us one sample does not say what variance there can be in the format.  So let's assume that it's really rigid:  the two fields are always surrounded by "Batch job ... success" and separated by spaces.  Then a regex might look like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Batch job (.*) (.*) success");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(log);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    String jobId = matcher.group(1);
    String jobType = matcher.group(2);
    //...
}
```

If there is more flexibility in the format then you need to design a more precise regular expression.

Comment: I think the `<` and `>` are part of the string (or rather `&lt` and `>`)

Comment: The message comes exactly in that format where <> are part of the string but when I do a string inspect I can see that the < is replaced with lt&;

Comment: Your expression is too greedy and wouldn't match it correctly. I would use (.*?)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `/<(.*?)>/` do ....

```
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("/<(.*?)>/");
Matcher matc = patt.matcher("Batch job <jobid> <jobtype> success");
if (matc.matches()) {
    String jobid = matc.group(1);
    String jobtype = matc.group(2);
}
```

The 2 strings `jobid` and `jobtype` will contain the strings between the `<` and `>` (not including `<` and `>`)